# How to avoid jQuery ajax submit when page refreshed?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have simple html page which is used to send text message.

The issue is: when I refresh the page it automatically submits with.
How to page submit in jQuery ajax when page is refresh.

html page

```
 <form action="#" id="messageform">
      <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Message"/>
 </form>
```

jQuery

```
 $("#messageform").submit(function(e) { 

     e.preventDefault();

     var mymessage = $('#message').val();//getting msg
     //do the stuff
     return false;
});
```

Comment: redirect after you submitted the data

Comment: where have you written js ? are you using php, if so you need to redirect to somewhere else and unset the post. So basically you can not stop refresh action but you can reset values on refresh so submit will not do anything.

Comment: Share your complete code.